# I have this errors whenever I start vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli, vite

I encounter this problem every time I start vite

```
上午9:49:42 [vite] new dependencies found: ant-design-vue/es, ant-design-vue/es/input/style, ant-design-vue/es/form/style, updating...
上午9:49:42 [vite] Failed to load source map for /node_modules/.vite/chunk-IVKUFRUM.js?v=f72e0228.
上午9:49:42 [vite] Failed to load source map for /node_modules/.vite/chunk-45TFAW5X.js?v=f72e0228.
上午9:49:43 [vite] Failed to load source map for /node_modules/.vite/vuex.js?v=f72e0228.
上午9:50:14 [vite] ✨ dependencies updated, reloading page..
```

It seems to cause the web page to start very slowly, I didn't find a similar problem

This is the development environment

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design-vue/pro-layout": "^3.1.3",
    "@ant-design/icons-vue": "^6.0.1",
    "ant-design-vue": "^3.0.0-alpha.9",
    "axios": "^0.20.0-0",
    "js-base64": "^3.7.2",
    "store": "^2.0.12",
    "vue": "^3.2.21",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.6.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.19",
    "less": "^4.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.3.2",
    "unplugin-auto-import": "^0.4.10",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.15.6",
    "vite": "^2.5.5",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.3.0"
  }
```

The following is the configuration of Vite does not have vueconfig by default, and I don't seem to have encountered any problems, so I didn’t add it

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import {resolve } from 'path'
import pkg from './package.json'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { AntDesignVueResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({

  define: {
    PKG: JSON.stringify(pkg.dependencies),
    'process.env': {baseUrl : 'http://192.XXX.XXX:56701'}
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    open: false, 
    base: "./ ", 
    proxy: { 
      
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://192.168.0.188:56701',
        changeOrigin: true,
        ws: true,
        rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
    }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    AutoImport({ 
      imports: 'vue',
    }),
    Components({
      dts: true,
      resolvers: [
        AntDesignVueResolver({
          importStyle: 'less',
        }),
      ]
    }),
  ],

  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: "@",
        replacement: resolve(__dirname, 'src')
      }
    ]
  },
  css: {
    postcss: {},
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        // DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: This plugin helped me deal with the problem.
https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-optimize-persist